# When has Peter ever changed his Web-Formula?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In *The Amazing Spider-Man 320*, we see Peter working on a new and improved webbing formula. Which other times has he changed said formula? And I'm not talking about let's say ice webs or acid webs, I'm strictly speaking about the times he changed the formula of his base webbing.

Comment: Are you looking for answers from the comics, movies, animated series? It would be better to mention that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the comics, there've been various references to Peter upgrading his base webbing formula over the years. Although most of the time, these upgrades were spoken of in the past tense, so we can't pinpoint exactly when all of them were implemented, or quite how many there were in total.

[Marvel Team-Up Vol 1 #56](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Team-Up_Vol_1_56)

[image]

[image]

[Fantastic Four Vol 1 #207](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_207)

[image]

[Peter Parker, The Spectacular Spider-Man Vol 1 #45](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_45)

[image]

[image]

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #320](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_320)

[image]

[image]

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 2 #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_2_1)

[image]

One of the ways he modified his webbing was to make it non-conductive, so it could be used more effectively against Electro.

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_5)

[image]

[Peter Parker, The Spectacular Spider-Man Vol 1 #50](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_50)

[image]

[Avengers Vol 1 #315](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_315)

[image]

And the organic webbing produced by the alien symbiote was apparently more flame-resistant than the artificial webbing he'd used prior to that, which was already somewhat flame-resistant in it's own right, due to being treated with asbestos. It's unclear whether Peter's webbing was always treated with asbestos, or whether that was an upgrade in itself. If it was an upgrade, it was an early one.

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #19](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_19)

[image]

[Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars #9](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_9)

[image]

Finally, when Dr. Octopus' mind inhabited Peter's body, during the [Superior Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Superior_Spider-Man) storyline, he revised the webbing formula once again to make it stronger and longer-lasting.

[Superior Spider-Man Vol 1 #21](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Superior_Spider-Man_Vol_1_21)

[image]

[image]

Doc Ock also made a solvent he could use to dissolve the new webbing if needed. It's unclear if Peter still uses this new formula now, but he did use it after initially regaining control of his body.

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 3 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_3_2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be fair, it was the 60's. If there's one thing the Fantasticast has taught me, almost everybody who fought the Human Torch  back then brought gear stuffed to the gills with asbestos.

Comment: So, if we use the information given, I think it might come down to 2 upgrades. 1 was made, I suppose, in the early 70s, after Spidey had already established himself. I think this made it non-conductive and more durable, being used in your first 3 examples. Then, a second upgrade in the McFarlane era made it very strong and heat resistant, and given your information, this is about where we're left at today.

Comment: In the Vulture example, he said he'd easily broken Spider-Man's webbing the last time they fought, which was in _Specactular Spider-Man #4-5_, published in 1977. Peter also mentioned that he was using a new webbing formula in _Fantastic Four #207_, published in 1979. This suggests that at least one upgrade was made in the late '70s.

Comment: Also, it's unclear whether Peter continued using the new webbing formula he came up with in _Amazing Spider-Man #320_, since that webbing was so strong that his web-shooters couldn't snip the weblines loose when he fired them. Either he stopped using that formula, or upgraded his web-shooters to be able to cut those stronger weblines.

Comment: Finally, when Dr. Octopus' mind was inhabiting Peter's body, he came up with stronger, longer-lasting webbing, and a solvent he could use to dissolve it when needed. I'm not sure if Peter still uses that new formula, but he did for a little while at least. I'll add the relevant scans to the answer later today.

Comment: "One of the ways he modified his webbing was to make it non-conductive, so it could be used more effectively against Electro." On the other side of that coin, there have been references in various properties over the years (I _think_ including comics, but definitely animated TV and etc.) to "electro-webs": not only conductive, but will carry sufficient current that they can be energized to shock targets.

Answer (score 15):

In the MCU at least Peter is always changing the web formula. In *Spider-Man: Homecoming* we see him working on *"Web Fluid 3.01"*. This of course indicates he has been changing it over the months/years to improve it.

[image: Homecoming: Web Fluid 3.0.1 formula]

We specifically see him creating this new version as well:

[image: Homecoming: Peter creating his web fluid]